# Excel VBA - Don't Allow Blanks if Other cell is filled in

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to add to the code below. I have a spreadsheet where end user can list a list of tasks and assign hours to each task, then hit a button and it submits to a task tracker.

What I'm trying to prevent is the end user entering a task and forgetting to put the hours in, and when submitting to the tracker, our totals being off because there's a blank.

In the code below, you'll see it looks down column D for models and E for model hours, then looks down I for drawings and J for drawing hours. But I'm not sure how to say "if there's data in D10 and there's not data in E10, and / or if there's data in I3 but not in J3, put up an error message that says "A task does not have hours assigned."

Any help would be appreciated!!

```
Function compareCols(rng As Range) As String
    Dim rngC1 As Range, cel As Range, i As Long
    Set rngC1 = rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each cel In rngC1.Cells
         If cel.Value <> "" And cel.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
            compareCols = "No hours in " & cel.Offset(0, 1).Address: Exit Function
         End If
    Next cel
    compareCols = "OK"
End Function

Sub CAD_Task_Entry()
Dim InstalDesc As String
Dim Model As Range
Dim Drawing As Range
Dim Index As Long
Dim m As Long, n As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Copy data from the input screen to the task list.
Sheets("Task Entry Form").Select
InstalDesc = Range("D3")
Set Model = Range("D5", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
Set Drawing = Range("I5", Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)

Index = Range("Q2")
With Sheets("Task List")
    'get first row
    n = .Range("D:X").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If n = 3 Then n = 4 Else n = n + 2
    
    'color first row
    .Range("A" & n & ":Z" & n).Interior.Color = 15189684
    .Cells(n, "D") = InstalDesc & " Summary"
    
    'verify hours are filled in on tasks
    Dim strOK As String
    strOK = compareCols(Model)
    If strOK <> "OK" Then MsgBox strOK: Exit Sub
  
    strOK = "": strOK = compareCols(Drawing)
    If strOK <> "OK" Then MsgBox strOK: Exit Sub
    
If Model.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Model.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Model.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Else
    Model.Columns(1).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Model.Columns(2).Copy
    .Cells(n + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If
  If Drawing.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Drawing.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
    .Cells(n + Model.Rows.Count + 1, "F").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Drawing.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
    .Cells(n + Model.Rows.Count + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Else
    Drawing.Columns(1).Copy
    .Cells(n + Model.Rows.Count + 1, "F").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Drawing.Columns(2).Copy
    .Cells(n + Model.Rows.Count + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

    'get last row after inserting data
    m = .Range("D:X").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    'create formulas
    'add backchecking and forumla
    .Cells(m + 1, 7) = "Backchecking"
    .Cells(m + 1, 17) = "=SUM(Q" & n + 1 & ":Q" & m & ")/2"
    'projected hours
    .Cells(n, "Q") = "=SUM(Q" & n + 1 & ":Q" & m + 1 & ")"
    'actual hours
    .Cells(n, "S") = "=SUM(S" & n + 1 & ":S" & m + 1 & ")"
    'install % complete
    .Cells(n, "U") = "=SUMPRODUCT(V" & n + 1 & ":V" & m + 1 & "+X" & n + 1 & ":X" & m + 1 & ",R" & n + 1 & ":R" & m + 1 & ")/SUM(R" & n + 1 & ":R" & m + 1 & ")"
        .Cells(n, "U").NumberFormat = "0%"
    'weight
    .Cells(n + 1, "R") = "=Q" & n + 1 & "/$Q$" & n
    .Cells(n + 1, "R").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("R" & n + 1 & ":R" & m + 1)
        'formatting weight
        With Range("R" & n & ":R" & m).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End With
        
    'create dropdowns
    'assigned to
     With .Range("T" & n & ":T" & m + 1).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Summary!$H$3:$H$14"
     End With
     
     'stages
     Sheets("Task List").Select
     For i = n + 1 To m + 1
        If Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
            .Range("W" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data!$B$4:$B$9"
            .Cells(i, "V") = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(W" & i & ",Data!$B$4:$C$9,2,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("W" & i).Value = "Not Started"
            .Range("T" & i).Value = Sheets("Summary").Range("H4").Value
            .Range("S" & i).Value = "0"
        End If
        If Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" Then
            .Range("Y" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data!$E$4:$E$15"
            .Cells(i, "X") = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Y" & i & ",Data!$E$4:$F$15,2,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("Y" & i).Value = "Not Started"
            .Range("T" & i).Value = Sheets("Summary").Range("H4").Value
            .Range("S" & i).Value = "0"
        End If
        If Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then
            .Range("Y" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data!$B$15:$B$16"
            .Cells(i, "X") = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Y" & i & ",Data!$B$15:$C$16,2,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("Y" & i).Value = "To Be Started"
            .Range("T" & i).Value = "Checker"
            .Range("S" & i).Value = "0"
        End If
    Next i
    
Range("A2").Select
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Reset_Form
Sheets("Task Entry Form").Select
Range("D3").Select
End Sub

'clear form
Sub Reset_Form()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Task Entry Form").Select
Range("D3").ClearContents
Range("D5:D22").ClearContents
Range("E5:E22").ClearContents
Range("J5:J22").ClearContents
Range("K5:K22").ClearContents
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the only other VBA in the file, on the tab they fill out prior to submitting to the tracker.

```
    Option Explicit

'copies drawings from data tab based upon dropdown selection

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address(0, 0) <> "D3" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim fnd As Range, LastRow As Long
    [D5:E22,I5:J22].ClearContents
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        With Sheets("data")
            LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            Set fnd = .Range("L:L").Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                With .Range("M" & fnd.Row & ":M" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    .Areas(1).Resize(, 2).Copy
                    Range("D5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    With Sheets("data").Range("O" & fnd.Row & ":O" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                        .Areas(1).Resize(, 2).Copy
                    End With
                    Range("I5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So, in case of `Model` columns pasting, the code should check if any value in first column does not have an empty string in all corresponding second column cells. And the same for `Drawing`. Would such an understanding be correct?

Comment: Yes... it should look down column D and if there's any data in any of the rows, there should be a corresponding number in Column E. If not, throw up the error box. Then it should look down column I, and if there are any rows with data in them, it should make sure there's data in the same row in column J, or else throw up the error box.

Comment: Oh, to be clear... "look down column D", but that starts in D5 per the current code (the top part has header information).

Comment: OK. A function to check the correspondence in discussion must be created and used before copying. I will post an answer in some minutes.

Comment: Please, test the function suggested in my answer and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next function, able to check if there are not empty correspondent cell in the second column of the analyzed range:

```
Function compareCols(rng As Range) As String
    Dim rngC1 As Range, cel As Range, i As Long
    If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        If rng.Cells(1, 1) <> "" And rng.Cells(1, 2) = "" Then
            compareCols = "No correspondent data in " & rng.Cells(1, 2).Address: Exit Function
        Else
            compareCols = "OK": Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    Set rngC1 = rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    For Each cel In rngC1.Cells
         If cel.Value <> "" And cel.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
            compareCols = "No correspondent data in " & cel.Offset(0, 1).Address: Exit Function
         End If
    Next cel
    compareCols = "OK"
End Function
```

Calling it just before copying will do the checking job, as (I understand) you need.

You should insert this code lines, above `If Model.Rows.Count > 1...` :

```
'your existing code
  Dim strOK As String
  strOK = compareCols(Model)
  If strOK <> "OK" Then MsgBox strOK: Exit Sub
  
  strOK = "": strOK = compareCols(Drawing)
  If strOK <> "OK" Then MsgBox strOK: Exit Sub
  If Model.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    'your existing code...
    '...
 'your existing code
```

**Edited**:

Please, test your adapted code, as it should... Not tested, of course:

```
Sub CAD_Task_Entry()
 Dim InstalDesc As String, Model As Range, Drawing As Range, Index As Long, m As Long, n As Long

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'Copy data from the input screen to the task list.
 Sheets("Task Entry Form").Select
 InstalDesc = Range("D3")
 Set Model = Range("D5", cells(rows.count, "D").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
 Set Drawing = Range("I5", cells(rows.count, "I").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)

 Index = Range("Q2")
 With Sheets("Task List")
    'get first row
    n = .Range("D:X").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    If n = 3 Then n = 4 Else n = n + 2
    
    'color first row
    .Range("A" & n & ":Z" & n).Interior.color = 15189684
    .cells(n, "D") = InstalDesc & " Summary"
    
    'new code part____________________________
    Dim strOK As String
    strOK = compareCols(Model)
    If strOK <> "OK" Then MsgBox strOK: Exit Sub
  
    strOK = "": strOK = compareCols(Drawing)
    If strOK <> "OK" Then MsgBox strOK: Exit Sub
    'end new code part________________________
    
    If Model.rows.count > 1 Then
        Model.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
        .cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Model.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
        .cells(n + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Else
        Model.Columns(1).Copy
        .cells(n + 1, "E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Model.Columns(2).Copy
        .cells(n + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If
  If Drawing.rows.count > 1 Then
        Drawing.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
        .cells(n + Model.rows.count + 1, "F").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Drawing.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
        .cells(n + Model.rows.count + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Else
        Drawing.Columns(1).Copy
        .cells(n + Model.rows.count + 1, "F").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Drawing.Columns(2).Copy
        .cells(n + Model.rows.count + 1, "Q").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If

    'get last row after inserting data
    m = .Range("D:X").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    
 End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Reset_Form
 Sheets("Task Entry Form").Select
 Range("D3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please see my response below... I tried to enter the code where I thought it would go, and I got an error. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @WaveWalker116 No, no, no... The function **should not be pasted inside a `Sub`**. Please, paste it somewhere below your existing `Sub`. Or in front of it. It doesn't matter where, but not inside the sub...

Comment: oh, okay, I added it outside the sub, and don't get that error. However, I now get another error. I put your code between 'If Model.Rows.Count > 1 Then' and 'Model.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy', but it highlights the "end with" at the very end of the code and gives the error "End With without With".

Comment: @WaveWalker116 You should place the code **as it is** above `If Model.Rows.Count > 1 Then`, **as it appears in my answer**...

Comment: I saw what I did wrong, I copied your code and pasted it, but I didn't see the {If Model.Rows.Count > 1 Then} was in the code you gave, so I ended up with 2 of those side by side. Just need the fresh eyes of a new day to see that. Okay, so now everything appears to be working (no debug errors), however, now when I run the Script, it says "No correspondent data in $L$1". And this happens even when all cells are filled in. I don't see any reason for the code to be looking at K or L. Thanks for the help FaneDuru... I'm trying to learn and it is VERY much appreciated!

Comment: @WaveWalker116 It should not be possible, if you correctly built the two involved ranges. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? I will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: unfortunately, it is confidential. I have edited the first post to include ALL VBA code in Module 1 and also added the only other VBA code in the workbook, which is on Sheet 2, which is the form they fill out. You've already been more than gracious with your time and effort, if this doesn't help, then I'll just have to tell end-users to not leave blanks. I don't want to take up more of your time than I already have. A huge thanks for everything you've done so far!

Comment: Please, use the updated function. I only added a line `msgbox rng.address` to send a message with the address of the range which is processed in the function. What does this message returns? It should be the range your code sent to the function...

Comment: I sent you a personal email, but from my work email... please check your spam folder in case it's in there!

Comment: @WaveWalker116 Please, test the updated function **Only the function**. It used to return that strange address **only when the range sent to the function has 1 row**. Otherwise, it worked with the previous code, too. Now, it also deals with single row ranges.

Comment: Yes! That got it to work... HUGE thanks for all your help!!!